# post nested object as formdata using x-www-form-urlencoded content-type

Tags: javascript, post, form-data, x-www-form-urlencoded

I have to send the data of post method where headers content-type is set to "x-www-form-urlencoded".

Also this form-data is nested object.
e.g.

`const formData = { name: "hello", email:abc@gmail.com, education: { subject: "engilsh" ... } } }`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `querystring` module.

Post the data like this Express-like pseudocode:

```
const querystring = require('querystring');

// ...

router.post(
  'https://api/url',
  querystring.stringify(formData),
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
)
```

// EDIT: The `querystring` module does not work with nested objects. My bad. I'd perhaps suggest serializing the object into a JSON string.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the problem you are experiencing is that the data received is shown as `education: [object Object]`.

The easiest way to resolve this problem is to change the header from `x-www-form-urlencoded` to `application/json`. That way the object with the key `education` won't be serialised into `[object Object]`

Another way to resolve this (but hacky) is to serialise the data client side:

```js
const formData = { name: "hello", email:abc@gmail.com, education: { subject: "engilsh" ... } } }
const formDataSerial = { raw: JSON.stringify(formData) }
// Send to server
```

And at the server, do another step of unpacking:

```js
const dataSerial = formData.raw
const data = JSON.parse(dataSerial)
// Yay!
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're working on converting nested objects into FormData with a focus on x-www-form-urlencoded content type. You can achieve this using a recursive function. Below is an example implementation:

```js
export function objectToFormData(obj, form = null, namespace = '') {
    const formData = form || new FormData();
    const isArr = Array.isArray(obj);

    for (const key in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key) || obj[key] === null || obj[key] === undefined) {
            continue;
        }

        const formKey = namespace ? (isArr ? `${namespace}[]` : `${namespace}[${key}]`) : key;

        if (obj[key] instanceof Date) {
            formData.append(formKey, obj[key].toISOString());
        } else if (obj[key] instanceof File) {
            formData.append(formKey, obj[key]);
        } else if (typeof obj[key] !== 'object') {
            formData.append(formKey, obj[key].toString());
        } else if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
            obj[key].forEach((item, index) => {
                const arrayKey = `${formKey}[${index}]`;
                objectToFormData(item, formData, arrayKey);
            });
        } else {
            objectToFormData(obj[key], formData, formKey);
        }
    }

    return formData;
}
```

Also, I have written **[nested-formdata](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nested-formdata)** library for this that you can use to convert nested object to form data easily